# How to create an oblique circle of points with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, vertices, faces

I created a program that define some vertices and faces and generate a cylinder in the Blender scene:

```
import bpy
import math
import mathutils

points = 10
step = ((math.pi* 2) / points)
x = 0
y = 0
current = 0
radius = 0.1
vertices = []
edges = []
faces = []
n_points = 5
n_step = 0
n_dist = 0

for iterator in range(0,n_points):
    for count in range(0,points):

        x = math.sin(current) * radius
        y = math.cos(current) * radius

        vertices.append((0+n_step,x,y))

        print("(",x,",",y,")")
        current += step

    for count in range(0,points):
        if(iterator >= 1):
            if(count != points-1):
                faces.append((count + iterator*points - points, count + iterator*points+1 - points,  count + iterator*points + 1, count + iterator*points))
            else:  
                faces.append((count + iterator*points - points, count + iterator*points - (points-1)-points, count + iterator*points - (points-1),count + iterator*points))

    n_step += 0.1


object_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("object_mesh")
object_mesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)
object_object = bpy.data.objects.new("object", object_mesh)
scene = bpy.context.scene 
scene.objects.link(object_object)
```

Following this philosophy I would like to generate a structure that is not just a cylinder but it's a bit more complex and it's shown in the following figure:
[image]
Each of the line in the figure is a circle of `points` points and they are connected exactly the same way I connected the points in the cylinder with my code. Generating the four sides shouldn't be a big problem but I can't understand how I can generate the oblique circles.
Just to make an example if this code create the upper part of the figure I am achieving, replacing the line `vertices.append((0+n_step,x,y))` with `vertices.append((0+n_step,x-0.5,y-0.5))` can generate the down part.
With some inversions, I think I can generate the side parts but how can I manage the four oblique circles?
Notice that I have to generate the circles **in order** if I want to add the faces as I am doing now. Of course I am opened to alternatives.

Comment: I may not understand your question. Do you want a single 90 degree rotated circle sharp corner ... or a series smoother circles at corner? Is this a exercise to use Python? Is it true you do not want to model this directly in Blender UI?

Comment: If you want to rotate a set of points 45 degrees about some axis, a suggestion is to search here at BSE using a Blender API to provide a matrix to perform rotation.  You may have an easy case here, but that may not last for long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Bmesh take on this.  Simplest to add a circle is using [Create Circle](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_68a_release/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_circle).  The oblique is a circle, scaled by the square root of 2 (Pythagoras) on one axis.

A sample script creates a ring facing front, and an oblique rotated 45, so as that in front ortho view it appears as the circle.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

from bmesh.types import BMFace as BMFace
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
from math import radians, sqrt

context = bpy.context

obj = context.object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Rings")

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)
# circle mesh
circle = bmesh.ops.create_circle(bm, diameter=1, segments=10)
# rotate up face front
bmesh.ops.rotate(
        bm,
        verts=circle["verts"],
        cent=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        matrix=Matrix.Rotation(radians(90.0), 3, 'X'))        
# make the oblique circle
oblique = bmesh.ops.create_circle(bm, diameter=1, segments=10)
#scale by root 2
bmesh.ops.scale(bm, vec=(sqrt(2), 1, 1), verts=oblique["verts"])
# rotate up face front
bmesh.ops.rotate(
        bm,
        verts=oblique["verts"],
        cent=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        matrix=Matrix.Rotation(radians(90.0), 3, 'X'))        
# and now by 45
bmesh.ops.rotate(
        bm,
        verts=oblique["verts"],
        cent=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        matrix=Matrix.Rotation(radians(45.0), 3, 'Z'))   
# feed to the mesh
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
# do the make object link to scene blah blah
scene = context.scene
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("RingTest", mesh)
scene.objects.link(ob)
scene.objects.active = ob
ob.select = True
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! I didn't know about the `create_circle` function. It works exactly as I expected.

Comment: Is there also a way to define and add faces before feeding the mesh?

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates the "oblique circle" that you need in the plane x=z, which, actually, is not a circle but an ellipse (the intersection of two cylinders):

```
for count in range(0,points):

    x = math.sin(current) * radius
    y = math.cos(current) * radius
    z = math.sin(current) * radius

    vertices.append((x, y, z))
```

Comment: Intersection of Plane and Cylinder?

Comment: Right: the oblique circles are also the intersection of a plane and a cylinder, but with the plane not being orthogonal to the cylinder axis (the angle is 45°). They are also the intersection of two cylinders with orthogonal axis.